# how to use <slot>, who can give me a sample demo?

Tags: vuejs2

I'm learning Vue framework, could not understand how to use [slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots), who can show me a sample demo please?
thanks a lot.

Comment: Slots are simply placeholders for data provided by parent to child. They tell where to place any given data. Refer to https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html for more info

Comment: I had already saw that link, could you please give me a sample demo like this https://jsfiddle.net/chrisvfritz/Lp20op9o/

Comment: check my answer. Ask if you still have any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick code example from https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots

Lets say you want to render the given template called 'base-layout'

```
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <!-- We want header content here -->
  </header>
  <main>
    <!-- We want main content here -->
  </main>
  <footer>
    <!-- We want footer content here -->
  </footer>
</div>
```

So you can see we have three slots 'header', 'main' and 'footer'.

If you write

```
<base-layout>
  <h1 slot="header">Here might be a page title</h1>

  <p>A paragraph for the main content.</p>
  <p>And another one.</p>

  <p slot="footer">Here's some contact info</p>
</base-layout>
```

Then the first `h1` tag value goes inside the slot named 'header' in our template.
And similarly other values.

---

The result would be

```
<div class="container">

<!-- this is where the 'header' slot was  -->
<h1>Here might be a page title</h1>

<!-- this is where the main slot was -->
<p>A paragraph for the main content.</p>
<p>And another one.</p>

<!-- this is where the footer slot was -->
<p>Here's some contact info</p>
```

So slots are basically like placeholder which can be named and you can send information at exact part.

Answer (score 0):

@Doc thank you for your answer and prompt. And i make out the demo:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>39、slot !</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="app">
        <alert-box>
            Something bad happened.
        </alert-box>
    </div>
    <script>
        Vue.component('alert-box', {
            template: `
                <div class="demo-alert-box">
                    <strong>Error!</strong>
                    <slot></slot>
                </div>
            `
        })
        var app = new Vue({
            el:'#app'
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```